# Using mongodb in store

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb for store, I need to find how frequency one item is selling. I know logic, but not syntactic way in mongo, assume I have 3 items, first itemA was sold in "2015-08-25 00:28:41", itemB "2015-08-25 00:29:05", itemC "2015-08-25 00:30:02", so I need to subtract C-B, B-A then add and divide 2. How can I do query for multiple items ? for example 100 items. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look into "aggregate" functionality of MongoDB? I assume this is the right way to go. You can use it for your task I am sure. See here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/

Comment: sure, I have looked, but I will need subtract , avg functions inside aggregation, I have tried but couldnt find correct query for this purpose.

Comment: I will need sort as well inside aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Seems your question is a bit more basic - **How to query MongoDB**.
So if your collection name is 'store' you will use:

```
db.store.find() // This will get all records.
```

If you want to sort it by date, you can add `.sort({ date: -1})` - will sort them.

Then adding `.limit(100)` will limit the results you will get, then you can carry on with whatever logic you need.

```
db.store.find().sort({ date: -1}).limit(100)
```

Comment: I need how frequency item is selling.. After sorting I will also need subtract each item from previous one, and find average of subtraction, you havent understood what I mean

Comment: I think I understood, you should do all those calculations in code - you mentioned you have the logic needed but just need a way to properly get the results. Just query all the items you need, based on a date since last query or some other filter, and then do the calculation in code.

Comment: I am trying to find solution in query, I have more than 2 millions record, I can do it in Java, but query is faster and I want to learn how it is done in query using aggregation.